# Linq: split list based on property value

Tags: c#, linq

When I have to create sublists basing on a property value, I can usually go with GroupBy extension method.

However now I have to create groups basing on property values, but keeping them in the original order, so that multiple groups will have the same key.

As an example, provided that for each element the relevant property has the following values

```
{0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2}
```

I need to have 5 separate groups in my output, with

```
{0: <three objs>}
{1: <two objs>}
{0: <two objs>}
{1: <three objs>}
{2: <three objs>}
```

What is the best linq-way to accomplish this?

Comment: You mean consecutive groups?! https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericwhite/2008/04/20/the-groupadjacent-extension-method/

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-results-by-contiguous-keys

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you are interested in creating intervals based on the same property value. This can be done with the following extension method.

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>
Intervals<T, R>(this IEnumerable<T> Input, Func<T, R> f)
where R : IEquatable<R>
{
    if (0 != Input.Count())
    {
        var CurrentValue = f(Sequence.First());
        Func<T, bool> IntervalPredicate = iEl => f(iEl).Equals(CurrentValue);
        return new IEnumerable<T>[]
               {Input.TakeWhile(IntervalPredicate)}
               .Concat(Input.SkipWhile(IntervalPredicate).Intervals(f));
    }
    else
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<IEnumerable<T>>();
    }
}
```

The argument `f` is used to project each object in the sequence `Input` to its desired propoerty. The result is a sequence of intervals of the input, based on equality of the value of the projection.